# Should I return a promise in a JS Service Worker onFetch callback function if I don't want to do anything with the original request?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

My scenario is the following:

1. I have a **Progressive Web App** that uses a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) where I need to *catch* the request and do something with it every time the user requests a resource or *leaves* the current URL
2. I'm handling that through adding a callback to the [fetch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent) of the worker
3. I only care about requested resources within our domain *(e.g. example.com)*
4. If the requested resource is within our domain I return the promise result from a regular `fetch`, so that's already covered
5. But, if the requested resource is outside my domain *(as shown in the below snippet)* I want the original request to just continue
6. I'm currently just doing a simple `return` if the scenario in bullet 5 is true

Snippet of my current code:

```
function onFetch(event) {
  if (!event.request.url.startsWith("example.com")) {
    return;
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      fetch(event.request)
        .then(req => {
          // doing something with the request
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
          // handle errors etc.
        })
        .finally(()=> {
          // cleanup
        })
    );
  }
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', onFetch);
```

My question: Is it OK if I just return nothing like in the snippet, or, do I need to return something specific, like a new promise by fetching the original request *(like I'm doing on the else block)*?

Thanks!

Comment: You should make it an async function for consistency and coherence. And make sure to return something in any case.

Comment: If you want external resources to still work, you need to handle it.  Also your totally ignoring caching here, every request will end up been a physical fetch, this will cause performance issues.

Comment: @Keith That's actually what I'm doing, caching certain requests if they meet certain criteria or just doing the fetch otherwise (in the else block) Also am not sure I understand the part of every request ending up being a physical fetch Thanks!

Comment: `physical fetch`,  a none cached fetch..  For when you don't do -> `caches.match(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is absolutely okay to do what you're doing. *Not* calling `event.respondWith()` is a signal to the browser that a given `fetch` handler is not going to generate a response to a given request, and you can structure your code to `return` early to avoid calling `event.respondWith()`.

You might have multiple `fetch` handlers registered, and if the first one returns without calling `event.respondWith()`, the next `fetch` handler will then get a chance to respond. If all of the `fetch` handlers have executed and none of them call `event.respondWith()`, the browser will automatically handle the request as if there were no service worker at all, which is what you want.

In terms of observed behavior, not calling `event.respondWith()` at all ends up looking similar to what would happen if you called `event.respondWith(event.request)`. But there is overhead involved in making  a `fetch()` request inside of a service worker and then passing the response body from the service worker thread back to the main program, and you avoid that overhead if you don't call `event.respondWith()`. So, I'd recommend the approach you're taking.